# How to separate (space between) numbers in tesseract OCR

Tags: split, numbers, ocr, tesseract, spacing

I try to get numbers from 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXect.png)

but after submitting my result is  2 332223355 1 23, i don't really understand how does it splits, everything i need is to split one, two and three digit numbers with space. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

> `tesseract -psm 7 NXect.png stdout`

which gives for the image you provided:

```
2 3 32 22 33 55 123‘
```

The tesseract version I am using:

```
$ tesseract --version
tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.73
  libgif 5.1.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

gives me for the original image without any options:

```
Error in pixGenHalftoneMask: pix too small: w = 250, h = 58
23 32 22 33 55 123
```

and for the resized image (2x):

```
$ tesseract  NXect_x2.png stdout
23 32 22 33 55 123
```

so I can't confirm the OCR result you are getting out the image.

Comment: Thanks  for quick answer, it helped me